# Add a related record in a modal form in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm creating a simple app in CakePHP that will be used to record members in a youth group, the idea being that many units around the country (similar to say Scout troops) can login and record new member details, and these records are available at a state and national level.

One of the fields recorded is the school that the new member attends, rather than just enter a text field the school is in a related table and the member 'belongsTo' the school.  This gives a nice little drop down field to select the school, however given there are thousands of schools in the country the schools list is by no means complete. To simplify data entry, rather than have the person entering the data either skip that field or have to create the school first, THEN add the member, I'd like to have the option of being able to create the school entry in a modal popup then returning back to the new member entry and having the new school available in the drop down.

I've found a few simplified examples in stack overflow but nothing that meets this need.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a dropdown of a distracting modal, why don't you simply use a autocomplete/typeahead field?

There are several examples arround like the [jQueryUI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) or the [Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) and many more if you do a search

You could even make it so that if a new value is entered it is added to the database and available for the next visitor as autocomplete